# A simple question on Periods Conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\omega$ is an algebraic form defined on $X$ which induces a nonzero element of the algebraic de Rham cohomology $\mathbb{H}^n(X)$. If $C$ is a nonzero element of $H_n(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$, the following integration defines a period
\begin{equation}
P=\int_C \omega
\end{equation}
I do not understand Kontsevich-Zagier period conjecture very well, and does it imply that $P$ is non-zero?

If so, is there a proof to this "simple" (I am not sure whether it is simple) case? Any useful references?

Comment: I do not know the Kontsevich-Zagier period conjecture, but if you take $X$ to be a product $Y\times Z$, if you define $\omega$ to be the pullback of a class from $Y$, and if you define $C$ to be a cycle in a fiber of projection to $Y$, then $P$ equals $0$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. Do you know any examples in case $X$ is not the product of two varieties?

Comment: A non-product counterexample is $X=\mathbb{A}^1\backslash\{0,1\}$, $\omega=dz/z$, and $\gamma$ is a loop around $1$.

Comment: There is no single Kontsevich-Zagier period conjecture, rather there are a collection of conjectures which can be divided into two categories

Comment: 1) Given a number can one figure out if it is a period in the sense you outlined above. Which naturally occurring numbers are periods, for example special values of all motivic L-functions are conjectured to be periods(this is explicitly stated on page 21 of their paper and attributed to Beilinson-Deligne-Scholl)

2) What does the set of all periods look like (it is a subset of complex numbers and contains all algebraic numbers). Can one find all the relations amongst periods.